# Passing Non-ID Variable Through Rails Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-2, ruby-1.8.7

Rails 2.3, Ruby 1.8.7

I'm trying to pass a variable through a rails route. I haven't been able to find a case where anyone was doing this with something that wasn't an id of a model. I'm not certain if that's the source of the problem.

In the view:

```
reference_string = "string of random letters and numbers"
something_path(reference_string)
```

In `routes.rb`:

```
map.something 'something/:reference_string', :controller => :my_controller, :action => "my_action", :reference_string => "reference_string"
```

In `my_controller`:

```
def my_action(reference_string)
  ...
end
```

I end up getting an Argument Error:

`wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`

Thanks in advanced

Comment: controller methods aren't methods. They are actions. They receive no arguments. The reference_string should be params[:reference_string] within your action code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller actions do not accept arguments.

Update your controller action so it looks like this:

```
def my_action
  ...
end
```

Then, to access `reference_string`, try `params[:reference_string]` anywhere in the controller or views. As an example, you could do this:

```
def my_action
  redirect_to root_url, :notice => "You sent us the reference string #{params[:reference_string]}!"
end
```